# How can I display data from a PostgreSQL database on a WordPress website?

Tags: wordpress, postgresql, web-applications, custom-wordpress-pages, postgrest

I am interested in learning how I can create a connection from my PostgreSQL database to my WordPress hosted website in order to build dynamic webpage templates. I have spent a good amount of time researching this topic but I came up short. I hope some of you won't mind sharing your knowledge on this topic with me.

Thank you in advance!